# how to override website's stylesheets?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

I'm looking for a way to customize some websites appearance using local css stylesheets. Preferably on firefox but a solution for any browser would be fine

I am aware there are some extensions like stylebot but i'd prefer something 'local'

Thanks

Comment: There are a variety of extensions which allow you to specifically add your own CSS. If you also want to, potentially, add your own JavaScript, the most popular is Tampermonkey. Using an extension that works on both Firefox and Chrome is probably your best bet. If you really want to have it be "local", in Firefox you can add a `userContent.css` file in a directory called "chrome" within your profile's directory. You'd have to use a bunch of `@-moz-document` directives to separate out the CSS by domain/page. This will be significantly less convenient than using an extension.

Answer (score 7):

Both Stylus and Stylish are available on Chrome and Firefox.

On Firefox: [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) and [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

On Chrome: [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) and [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)

You can browse popular styles made by other users on [Userstyles.org](https://userstyles.org).

Comment: Nice thing that stands out about Stylus is that it's got the [Recommended](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-badges#w_recommended-extensions) badge on AMO (Mozilla/Firefox). Tried it out and works very well.

Comment: Yes, Stylus would be my preferred choice nowadays, since UserStyles and Stylish were bought by some digital marketing/web analytics company.